How to get a total sum based on a certain columns containing the same value
A dataframe has columns code1, code2, code3 etc., with codes stored in them. For each code, there is a column with number of days used days_used1, days_used2, days_used3 etc. I want to get a dataframe including a column for each code which has the days_used summed for each of the values in code.
data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6),
            code1 = c('D', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'G', "A"),
           quantity1 = c(10, 10, 15, 30, 20, 10),
           dose1 = c(5, 5, 15, 0.5, 2, 10), 
           days_used1 = c(NA, NA, 90, 63, 20, 50),
           code2 = c('A', 'H', 'D', 'G', 'A', "A"),
           quantity2 = c(5, 10, 10, 20, 20, 5),
           dose2 = c(0.1, 15, 15, 7, 5, 12), 
           days_used2 = c(15, NA, NA, 50, 20, 10),
           code3 = c('A', 'H', 'C', 'A', 'D', "D"),
           quantity3 = c(10, 10, 15, 30, 20, 10),
           dose3 = c(5, 5, 15, 0.5, 2, 10), 
           days_used3 = c(15, NA, NA, 50, 20, 10)
 )

So I want a dataframe looking like this:
data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  A= c(30, 0, 0, 20, 60),
                  D = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 10),
                  C= c(0, 0, 90, 0, 20, 10),
                  G= c(0, 0, 0, 50, 20, 0),
                  H= c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
)

I don't really know how I can get this done. I tried something along the ways of the example below, but this obviously does not work
ifelse(test[paste0("code",c(1:3))] == "A",
         sum(test[paste0("code",c(1:3)) == "A"]+1), 
         0)
     code1 code2 code3
[1,]     0     0     0
[2,]     0     0     0
[3,]     0     0     0
[4,]     0     0     0
[5,]     0     0     0
[6,]     0     0     0


library(data.table)

dcast(
      melt(setDT(test), id=1L,
           measure=patterns("^code", "^days"),
           value.name=c("Code", "Days"))[,
            .(sumDays = sum(Days, na.rm = T)), 
            .(ID, Code)],
      ID  ~ Code, value.var = c("sumDays"), fill = 0)

#>    ID   A  C  D  G H
#> 1:  1  30  0  0  0 0
#> 2:  2   0  0  0  0 0
#> 3:  3   0 90  0  0 0
#> 4:  4 113  0  0 50 0
#> 5:  5  20  0 20 20 0
#> 6:  6  60  0 10  0 0

Created on 2024-04-23 with reprex v2.0.2

We could pivot with the column names split at the last character, then count by ID and code, and spread that:
library(tidyverse)
df |>
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c(".value", "obs"), names_sep = -1) |>
  count(ID, code, wt = days_used) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = code, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
  

Result
# A tibble: 6 × 6
     ID     A     D     H     C     G
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    30     0     0     0     0
2     2     0     0     0     0     0
3     3     0     0     0    90     0
4     4   113     0     0     0    50
5     5    20    20     0     0    20
6     6    60    10     0     0     0


(more explanation)
After the first pivoting step, we'd have
# A tibble: 18 × 4
      ID obs   code  days_used
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1     1 1     D            NA
 2     1 2     A            15
 3     1 3     A            15
 4     2 1     D            NA
 5     2 2     H            NA
 6     2 3     H            NA
 7     3 1     C            90
 8     3 2     D            NA
 9     3 3     C            NA
10     4 1     A            63
11     4 2     G            50
12     4 3     A            50
13     5 1     G            20
14     5 2     A            20
15     5 3     D            20
16     6 1     A            50
17     6 2     A            10
18     6 3     D            10

Then we can sum by ID and code. (Alternatively, we could run ... |> summarize(n = sum(days_used), .by = c(ID, code)) but I prefer the count() syntax when we're just summing groups.
# A tibble: 13 × 3
      ID code      n
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1     1 A        30
 2     1 D         0
 3     2 D         0
 4     2 H         0
 5     3 C        90
 6     3 D         0
 7     4 A       113
 8     4 G        50
 9     5 A        20
10     5 D        20
11     5 G        20
12     6 A        60
13     6 D        10


My dataframe has some more colums inbetween, which can be disregarded (see edit). Also, the structure of the columns differs. For the first step I tried data |>     pivot_longer(cols=c(p_id, starts_with("code"), starts_with("days_used")), values_transform = list(p_id = as.character, code= as.character, days_used = as.numeric)), but I still get  Can't combine p_id <character> and days_used1 <double>
